# Seekbar Issue for FFMPEG?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I implemented FFMPEG library for one of my application in android. It is working fine for most of the songs.

For few songs when i scroll the song duration...then at that time the current song duration not showing exact duration.

I unable to find out the issue whether it is w.r.t to particular song or different bit rate songs so on ?....

Here my code for Seekar progress..

```
int ret = av_seek_frame(fmt_ctx, seekStreamIndex, seekTime,flags);
```

Please suggest me a better solution.

Comment: Please provide a sample audio clip that exhibits this issue.

Comment: Hi,its working fine for most of the songs but problem with some mp3 songs